# window.content.mozInnerScreenY value is not working in Firefox 33.1

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am writing a Mozilla extension to calculate the Y Screen off-set by using this **"window.content.mozInnerScreenY"** API. After upgrading firefox to 33.1 version I am not able to view Mozilla in a maximized window, though selecting to view in Maximized window it gets back to smaller window size. Just to double check i commented this line of code in extension's logic ,then window sizing works good.

Why the above value is not working for me. kindly help me to troubleshoot this issue.
code is as bellow:

```
**var  appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
var myExtension = {  
    init: function() {  
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.           
          if(appcontent)
           { 
              appcontent.addEventListener("resize", this.onmyPageResize, false);
           }               
      },  
    onmyPageResize: function(aEvent) {  

        screenY= window.content.mozInnerScreenY;
        //Process screenY
    }  
}

 window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){  
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed  
   myExtension.init();    
},false);**
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant source code?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni 

`code` var myExtension = {  
        init: function() {  
               
        if(appcontent)
            { 
                   appcontent.addEventListener("resize", this.onmyPageResize, false);
            }       
          },  
        onmyPageResize: function(aEvent) {  
             screenY= window.content.mozInnerScreenY;
   //Processing ScreenY
    }
    
 window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){  
        window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed  
       myExtension.init();    
    },false); `code`

Comment: It's better to add it in the main question. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change worked for me.
i made a very minor change in the above code :

**const** screenY = window.content.mozInnerScreenY.

i just changed screenY as **const** type since **window.content.mozInnerScreenY** is a **read-only** value.

This change fix the issue.